# Html.BeginForm posting a different model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view for a filtering panel such as;

```
@model TabNetMVC.Models.FixedAsset.BarcodeTrackingModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ApprovalList", "BarcodeTracking", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RestaurantNo, Model.Restaurants, new { @class = "form-control", id = "restDropDown" })
    <input onclick="" type="submit" name="name" value="Apply Filter" />
}
```

Here, I am receiving a model with type of `BarcodeTrackingModel`and then populating the Restaurant names into my dropdown list via `Model.Restaurants`. `Model.Restaurants` is a List of `SelectListItem` type objects. I want user to choose a restaurant and then the value of this choice will be overwritten on the existing model's `RestaurantNo` property. For this purpose, I have passed an expression as the first parameter to my `DropDownListFor` method like this; `model => model.RestaurantNo`. My problem is that, whenever I click on the "Apply Filter" button and submit the form, the model is passed to the Action method `ApprovalList` is nulled with all of its properties except the `RestaurantNo` property. So, only the selected value on dropdownlist is passed to action method and another data on the existing model is lost. In other words, the form is posting a different model then the existing `Model` which it consumes. Here is the action method;

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ApprovalList(BarcodeTrackingModel model)
        {
            model.ProductList = model.ProductPagedList.Where(p => p.RestaurantNo == model.RestaurantNo).ToList();

            return View("~/Views/BarcodeTracking/List.cshtml", model);
        }
```

What can be causing this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your exemple the submit will post only RestaurantNo wich is between { } of your form, if you have any other properties and you don't want to display it use hidden field otherwise you can use Jquery to post this property

Comment: @Amine, I want to post back the whole same Model back, only with RestaurantNo field is filled.

Comment: If you want to post the RestaurantNo, what you did should work but if you want to post all model (many fileds) you should use hidden field for all properties or use TempData["Model"]=yourModel.

Answer (score 1):

You only send the information that is in your form, in this case, the only data you are sending is

> model.RestaurantNo

you can send more parameters from hidden fields, but i don't understand what are you trying to accomplish, sorry for not being more helpful.

Comment: To expand on what Edgar is saying, only form fields that are located within the `<form></form>` tags are sent. This is is true no matter what language/framework you are using (ASP.NET, PHP, JSP, Ruby, etc). So what you will want to do is maybe put a `Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)` in the form, then in your controller action, get the data from the database, then return the product list.